# How can I check if one specific login has any database users mapped on it?

Tags: sql-server, logins

I've create some logins and database users. So I would like to accomplish the following.

Drop user from database:

```
USE [dbname]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysusers WHERE NAME = 'username')
    DROP USER [username]
```

Here I would like to check if the login has any database users in other databases and if not drop login:

```
USE [master]
GO
DROP LOGIN [username]
GO
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: until now no, but I want to make a safe query

Answer (score 3):

use this query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#results', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #results;

CREATE TABLE #results(
    LoginName sysname
    ,LoginType nvarchar(60)
    ,IsMustChange bit
    ,DatabaseName sysname NULL
    ,DatabaseUserName sysname NULL
    ,DatabaseRoleName sysname NULL
    );

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb '
USE [?];
INSERT INTO #results
    SELECT
        sp.name AS LoginName
        ,sp.type_desc AS LoginType
        ,CAST(LOGINPROPERTY ( sp.name , ''IsMustChange'' ) AS bit) AS IsMustChange
        ,DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
        ,dp.name AS DatabaseUserName
        ,r.name AS DatabaseRoleName
    FROM sys.server_principals sp
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON
        dp.sid = sp.sid
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_role_members drm ON
        drm.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals r ON
        r.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id
    WHERE sp.name = ''SomeLogin''';

SELECT * FROM #results;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#results', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #results;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to answer to your second question, maybe you'll change your idea of dropping not mapped logins.

> here I would like to check **if the login has any database users in
> other databases and if not drop login** USE [master] GO DROP LOGIN
> [username] GO

This approach can **grant** access to some login, in contrary as you think.

In many organizations `Windows groups` are widely used. This way by creating `login` as `Windows group`, and next creating `user` from this `login` you grant access to some databases to many people at once, any member of this `Windows group` will has access to some databases.

But sometimes it happens that some member of this group **should not access the server at all**. In this case you create the dedicated login for this person (login = Windows account) and deny `CONNECT SQL` to this login.
Other members of this `Windows group` still access databases, and this login does not. Of course there is no need to map this login to any database as the only scope of creating it was to `deny` the access to this login.

Now if you do what you want, you'll find this login as one that **has no mapping** to any database but **as soon as you drop it you'll give it the access** to all the databases to which that group has access. So think twice befor you drop it and at least check if the login has deny `CONNECT SQL`.

Comment: Basically I would like to check if given login  has no user in any database and it is not sysadmin.